# Redux-Form file upload after async validation

Tags: react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a FileUpload component that is connected through a redux-form Field. It calls input.onChange and input.onBlur with the selected file as a base64 string when a file is selected in an input field.

I'm using the asyncValidator redux-form option to validate the dimensions of the image, and I would like the file to be uploaded to the my server after the async validation has finished.

There doesn't seem to be any sort of afterAsyncValidation hook documented. What is the best way to accomplish this in redux-form?

Answer (score 1):

`redux-form` was designed with the idea that your data would be saved to the server on *submit*.

However, there's nothing stopping you from putting your own `.then()` clause after your async validation to do that. Something like this?

```
// async function you already have that is looking at your
// picture field and rejecting the promise with errors
import validateDimensions from './validateDimensions'

// async function to upload the image
import upload from './uploadImage'

const MyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
  asyncValidate: values =>
    validateDimensions()
      .then(() => {
        // we know validation passed
        upload(values.prettyPicture)
        // ^ not "return upload(values.prettyPicture)" to let this async
        // validation promise resolve and do upload asynchronously
        // after it has resolved
      })
  },
  asyncBlurFields: [ 'prettyPicture' ]
})(MyForm)
```

Comment: suppose I add another async validation to my form. Doesn't this run all async validations again, thus, causing the file to be re-uploaded again?

Comment: Yes, which is why it is not the intended use of `asyncValidate`.

Comment: @ErikR. is there any way to get it to perform HTML submission with a target `iframe` so that we can support old browsers?

Comment: @Andy You can do old-fashioned form submission all you want. It sort of side-steps the benefits of redux-form, but....

Comment: @ErikR. I came up with a semi-hacky solution where my `onSubmit` callback first calls `handleSubmit` injected by `redux-form` to validate, then calls `form.submit()` again with a flag set to bypass `handleSubmit` so that that `preventDefault()` doesn't get called and old-fashioned form submission goes through.  (Along with using a target `iframe` so that there's no page reload).  This was all for the sake of supporting a file upload

Comment: @ErikR. what would your `upload` function above actually do?  Wouldn't it have to be something new that isn't possible in older browsers?